# Slick Carousel - Reversing order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I am using Slick Carousel on a site I am developing.

An issue I am facing is attempting to get the "slider-nav" to move in the opposite direction to the standard.

Example:-

Currently the order is as follow:-

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I need it to run as the following:-

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

I know I could just reverse the order I am pushing then in but I need the following to happen:-

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
1 6 5 4 3 2
2 1 6 5 4 3
etc...
```

I have attempted to set the "slidesToScroll" as a -1 (as I have seen ) but this just causes my page to crash even on fiddle.

My current code look like:-

```
 $('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
  autoplay: true,
  centerMode: false,
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 5,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: false,
  centerMode: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
});
```

Basic setup:-

https://jsfiddle.net/5cyqtvt6/9/

I have also attempted to use the rtl settings but this for some reason just starts to show empty slides.

Eg.
https://jsfiddle.net/5cyqtvt6/14/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by adding

```
<div class="slider-for" dir="rtl">
```

and

```
<div class="slider-nav" dir="rtl">
```

and also updating the jQuery to the following:-

```
 $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    autoplay: true,
    centerMode: false,
    rtl: true
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    rtl: true
});
```

Working jsFiddle:-
https://jsfiddle.net/5cyqtvt6/16/